# Should I require to install any other files to get support of Javascript in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, selenium

I am using Selenium Webdriver, Java and Eclipse. I want to execute following code , but seems getting invalid type error for many types :

**Code :**

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('firefox')
.build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

Getting many red line errors. So does it require any external JARs to get support for Javascript with selenium webdriver?

Comment: This is perfectly-working JavaScript, and it works great when I save as a `wd.js` and run `node wd.js` on it. But it'll never run as Java. I think you need to clarify whether you really want Java or JS to avoid confused answers.

Comment: @AndrewRegan - Thanks for your input. Actually I am going to automate diagram applicatio of GoJS , And I found , that can be done by only JS scripts so I wanted to make sure that how we can run and automate javascript code via selenium and eclipse. So you mean I should save my file as .Js? instead of Java?

Comment: Yes, I think forget about Java here, and stick to JS. Surely you can just automate using GOJS's own API, rather than simulating usage via WebDriver?

Comment: I see, Let me try something and will update you.